# What are the Android naming conventions for colors with alpha?

Tags: android, colors, naming-conventions, alpha, conventions

I have text color with alpha.
Is it good idea to name color like black_20 where 20 is 20% opacity?

I would like to find some general convention which will work fine in bigger team with more exotic colors that most of people cannot immediately recognize by name.

We use this tool for non-alpha colors http://chir.ag/projects/name-that-color/#6195ED.

Answer (score 2):

Normally all of the naming conventions follow this convention :

WHAT_WHERE_DESCRIPTION_SIZE

This can be followed for colors also, but you dont need to specify WHAT, so it will be :

WHERE_DESCRIPTION_SIZE

for example : If you want to name a color blue with an alpha 50 , you can use the name as blue_50